# What is the equivalent of promise<void> in observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

I am using angular, so typescript, and try to return a promise from an observable.

What is the right way to do this?

I tried:

```
of(EMPTY).toPromise() // error: Promise<Observable<never>>' is not assignable to type Promise<void>

of(null).toPromise() // no error but not sure if it is the right way

of().toPromise // error: Promise<Observable<unknown>>' is not assignable to type Promise<void>
```

**Update:**

// this is the interface that declares it

```
export interface CustomStoreOptions extends StoreOptions<CustomStore> {   
   /** Specifies a custom implementation of the remove(key) method. */
    remove?: ((key: any | string | number) => Promise<void> | JQueryPromise<void>);   
}
```

so it is called:

```
let store = new CustomStore({     
        remove: key => {
          // return ...
        }
      });
```

Comment: Can you post the whole function declaration, because I think the errors are caused by mismatch between the declared and actual return types.

Answer (score 5):

You can write it as follows to get the equivalent of `Promise<void>`

```
 of(void(0))
```

You can also create a Subject that emits no data

```
 const s = new Subject<void>();
 s.next(void(0));
```

Comment: Why not `of(undefined)`? `of(void(0))` is going to confuse people.

Comment: Yes, it is the same. Actually undefined === void(0) evaluates to true. 
The reason I suggested this void(0) is because Promise<void> is treated differently than Promise<undefined>.  And since the question wanted to have a Promise<void> it would be more confusing to use let x: Promise<void> = of(undefined).toPromise() than using let x: Promise<void> = of(void(0).toPromise()

The difference is subtle, but since the type has void, I use void(0).